# Is there a way to get dagster the deamon / source location metrics?

Tags: dagster

On occasion I have code location failing to load or crashing due to a bug in my code.

Obviously I need to resolve the bug, but also, I would be able to alert on the error.

I noticed dagster itself is able to detect issues with code location and I am wondering if there are ways to extract these metrics, possibly through a prometheus endpoint or other mechanism.

I noticed dagster itself is able to detect this (failing code location, see image),
but I have not been able to monitor on this event.

I read the docs on [hooks](https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/hooks) and [prometheus](https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/libraries/dagster-prometheus) but these are all on `Job` level.

Is there a way to gather these statistics on deamon or orchestrator level?

[image]